# What type of geopolitical status quo can lead to perpetual warfare becoming the norm?

Tags: geopolitics

I want my world to have constant lower level conflict between powerful states, because that gives me lots of stories to write about. I was wondering what type of geopolitical situation can lead to perpetual warfare becoming the norm.

There are some rules, though:

1. The warfare can't be too devastating, like the Roman-Persian Wars were, because that will be too grimdark. So the conflict needs to be limited and short.
2. The conflict needs to happen for pragmatic reasons. No warfare for the sake of it, because that will quickly deplete all factions and lead to collapse of the status quo.
3. There must be lulls in the violence so that all factions can duly lick their wounds and recover for another round. So no Total Warfare that leaves the defeated side in ruins.
4. The status quo should not change too much. The balance of power needs to be maintained.

I don't really know much about geopolitics, but I've read a little history and feel that maybe Classical Greece and Post-Napoleonic Europe (before WW1) might be a good example of such a state. But I don't have the education to understand what factors these two eras had in common that allowed for this status quo.

Comment: so basically like 90% of human history?

Comment: (1) The Roman-Persian wars were so devastating that they continued for about *eight centuries*. In the end, the eternal never-ending Roman-Persian wars were only ended by the Muslim conquest. (2) You may want to count how many years of peace have France or Spain had between say 815 and 1815. (3) Just use the continuous post-medieval wars of Spain against just about everybody else... (4) Post-Napoleonic western Europe was unusually peaceful; the only wars were occasioned by the revolutions of '48, and even those degenerated into actual wars in eastern Europe -- Poland, Hungary, Transylvania.

Comment: I don't really want some Congo War/Syria level anarchy of bloodshed. I want just enough wars for a Heroic Fantasy.

Comment: @Thales look up the 100 year war that is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Not Politics: Geography.

I think what you are looking for is several large, stable empires that somehow aren't consumed with the desire to destroy each other, yet keep fighting significant wars. Short of a 1984-type world, I think the secret lies in geography, not politics.

You need border regions with valuable resources, symbolic sites (religious, cultural), and good trade access. They should be easy to access by all sides (islands with lots of ports, mountainous-enclosed but with defendable passes) so hard to defend, easy to invade, hard to attack homelands from. The populations will have grown accustomed to war, with adaptations to it (crops hard to burn, food hidden, pacifists who refuse to fight for any side) so they don't degrade significantly with time.

Thus the sides keep trying to obtain control of the valuable resources and the prestige sights for bragging rights, to drive up income and get favorable trade, secure useful minerals or access to trade towns with artisans, etc. Each Emperor can keep score on their greatness by how large they can expand their territory, but most regions wouldn't be in anyone's control for more than a generation or so. If the fighting gets too intense in any one area, the value of it goes down as war ravages it. The longer an area is peaceful, the more valuable it becomes and the more motive for an opposing faction to attack.

## Cultural muddling & History:

Cultural and economic demands can add spice to the mix by creating a variety of scenarios in which wars will inevitably break out. A string of strategic islands (think the Caribbean) can be an endless source of conflict. Power 1 seeks to control trade routes. Power 2 keeps restricting trade routes through the area with harassment to stop #1 from gaining control. Power 3 wants a base to project power from, or send out missionaries, or has some cultural ties to the area. Or perhaps the locals want independence, and #3 is their best shot (plus #3 wants to disrupt #1 & #2).

Colonial ambitions can provide a nice proxy for full-scale war, and keep conflict far from the borders of the empires themselves. Severely divided border regions with multiple religious, ethnic, and political entities can consume entire generations in petty conflicts. #1 controlled the region once and has historical claims. #2 married an Emperor's daughter to a local Duke and "defends family claims." #3 sells weapons and/or grain in the region, and stability would make the area self-sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

If you have powerful states fighting each other, you need both the technological/industrial and political conditions which keep this from becoming a total war which exhausts one or more of the involved states.

- The United States and Russia could not fight a long war today, because sooner or later one of the belligerents would go nuclear rather than a slow, grinding defeat.
- World War I or II could not have gone much longer than they did because in both cases, Germany's economy was about to collapse. In the case of World War I, while German troops stood deep in France and deeper in Russia.

So one option is what happened during the 1815-1914 era, fierce competition **in the colonies** while not going to war in Europe all that often. There were plenty of arms races and war scares, but the big wars happened because Germany formed, which was not originally one of the powerful nations.

The other option would be to have a **large pool** of more or less equal states, and to have one utterly defeated every now and then. A bit like the classic Greek model.

Neither seems to be quite what you require. So let's look at two different eras, the 17th century in Germany and the 18th century in central Europe.

- The [Thirty Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War) was a religious war, but also a fight for power and influence. Some of the factors which allowed it to go on, year after year:

  - Different outside powers (Sweden, France, ...) did enter the conflict, bringing fresh resources and never getting *their* heartlands wasted. Note how this mirrors the Cold War, with US troops in Vietnam and Russians in Afghanistan.
  - The war covered a large area, and it did not have battles everywhere all the time. Armies could requisition many supplies and also recruits from the areas they marched through.
  - Changing sides, even several times, *was* a survivable option for the productive population. The warlords wanted to terrorize and exploit them, not exterminate them.
- Many 18th century wars were fought for *limited purposes*, like [one province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Silesian_War), or at least by pretext about which branch of a dynasty would get a certain throne ([Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Spanish_Succession), [Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Austrian_Succession)).

  - Again, it was survivable for the people of a conquered region to change sides. They were more or less expected to go along with the outcome of the kings' quarrels.
  - Again, only a small part of the involved countries was a warzone at any one time.

So there is your recipe:

1. Multiple belligerents help, both to get shifting alliances and to cope with the defeat of any one side.
2. Fight so that the main productive areas of the belligerents remain a sanctuary. Only the region in between gets devastated.
3. Make the region in between large enough so that you can have clashes *somewhere* every campaign season.
4. Exploit the productive capacity of the conflict region, but do not employ a [scorched earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorched_earth) strategy as a *general* policy. Allow the populations to switch sides.

Answer (score 4):

The entire cold war period, from the end of WWII until the collapse of the Iron Curtain, was more or less what you want.

USA and USSR never directly faced each other, but rather fought proxy wars here and there, with the pragmatic reason of protecting people from the negative influence of the "other" side, only shifting few digits after the coma in the relative balance of power.

Comment: But they never fought each other at all.

Comment: @Thales that doesn't matter in this case. Let's say there's a Vietnam for the USA and a Ukraine for the Russians. Even though not a single shot is fired at the other nation, their men die in the war. You just support a nation with weapons and training,like communists did in Vietnam and the West currently does in Ukraine. It is still a war, but because we're 'not directly involved' it is ok. This can backfire, where some groups like Wagner were supporting some group. America saw no actual Russians present, so could bomb it to hell with impunity.

Answer (score 3):

## Population control

Two or more large nations are fighting. Is annihilation of the other feasible, or even possible?

Theoretically yes, but in practice it'll be next to impossible. You need to get the strategic advantage in so many ways to not break yourself, as the Ukraine war is also showing. Even if the military is victorious, you'll have so many people against you still. They are unhappy, which can be a great toll on your empire. But before that can happen you'll likely run into moral issues, supply lines, weapon shortages, dissidence on the home front for the families going to war.

Not to mention war is simply economically rarely positive. War is detrimental for normal growth. Current economic models have included military spending in special ways so people do not complain too much about it, but the value for a country, besides deterrent, is negative. You only spend on something you need to store and maintain, or use and lose.

### Control

Why then have a war? A small scale war can still have it's benefits. In the current climate between Russia and 'the West' there is suddenly more cohesion within each faction. With proper care, you can get more control over a population. Propoganda, laws and the like can much easier be accepted. Ask about military spending for the EU 5 years ago and they laugh. No one wanted to disappoint their voters. Better to put it into something the people see as useful for them. Ask them now and the support for military spending is very strong.

The two countries can realise this, and can even work together to keep a low key war going to both control their populations better.

### Polulation

The population is also an interesting point. You might have a growth that is unsustainable. Sure we can see if it finds any healthy equilibrium somewhere, but why wait and hope if you can actively control the growth? Send certain amounts of people to the front! Some die, some become heroes for your propoganda, some territory is taken and lost. The big nations look at each other, nod and move some around so no one starts touching WMDs. Maybe some less people to the grinder for now and more propaganda, so when needed you can send some more people to their deaths.

Cold and calculated control from the nations over their own population is a valuable commodity, in exchange for some smaller(satellite) war.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the answers i found a surprising lack of real world examples that i have the feeling should still be mentioned. Those examples which have been mentioned like **"The Cold War"** won't be mentioned separately though.

**1. A Stalemate:**

- This for conflict is generally between 2. powers that are equally matched and generally the kind of "Forever War" i used in my world.
- For this both sides must see winning the war as something existential that they must win.
- Very important here is that you keep the balance of power as 1. Side getting to strong destroys the whole balance.
- This kind of war also relatively versatile in how much conflict you want. Though keep in mind that both sides here are on their limit.
- Closest real world example might be the **100 year war** though i am sure there are others.

**2. Frozen Conflict:**

- Pretty much what 1. turns into from time to time or can for a longer period of time time if you want it too.
- Usually here a longer term cease fire is agreed upon though there could be other reasons for it too. Though tensions remain high.
- This is probably the **most versatile option** as you can apply to almost any conflict. And can restart the conflict whenever your story demands it.
- Real world examples are the whole **"Israel-Palestine"** conflict and the **"Korea war"** if you want to be specific.

**3. Guerilla War:**

- Is basically a war between a stronger power and some local forces.
- Because of asymmetrical warfare it is very hard for the stronger power to stomp out the weaker one.
- Normally this only ends with the stronger power giving up. Though if the stakes are to high this might not be an option.
- Probably **not the most versatile** of conflict and better used to accompany any conflict to keep tensions high.
- Real world examples are basically the USA in the Middle East but if you want to be more specific look up **"Afghanistan"**

**4. Heightened Tensions:**

- Technically not a war but for this scenario it can just be treated as such.
  Also technically the "Cold War" is part of this category but does not really represent this kind of conflict in its totality.
- Basically you have two powers that don't like each other but can't easily get rid of the other.
- This can lead to a cold war competition but doesn't have to necessarily. You could also have 2. powers fighting a series of wars for dominance.
- This is probably the most **long-term sustainable** kind of conflict and really it can go on for centuries.
- It is probably a good setup for your general conflict to lead over to what you want. As with this one there are generally a lot of piece periods in between which you may not want. Though i don't think it has to necessarily be that way.
- Real-life examples are the whole thing **France** had going on with the **British** or The **Germans**.

So that are all examples i have so far. Please if you think i made mistake somewhere tell me in the comments and I'll make sure to correct it.

*Note: English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar or spelling errors.*

Answer (score 0):

**Technology itself is destabilizing by its very nature**

To be more specific, technology is actually a peace-bringer, as in it stabilizes harvests and living conditions, resulting in a long lasting episode of peace, stability and prosperity, that could be easily mistaken by those prone to self-flattery for a changed nature as a species.

However- the technologies of warfare, are ever more destabilizing, as they reward asymmetric attack and punish defenders. The guards keeping the power-monopoly of a state, are almost always in the defending role. Thus from the introduction of the ak-47/FAL, to the IED, FPV drone and seadrone - there is a clear pattern that once a region descends into perma-conflict, in which nobody can re-establish a state and stabilize the region on its own.

In to many ways can be the supply lines rerouted, giving the "perma"-war a eternal basis of bullets, guns and DIY-explosives. Extreme expensive external effort has to be applied to re-stabilize a region. And even then- the original culture is gone, replaced by could be best described as "cyberpunk lord of the flies" with no ability to even establish permanent warlord fiefdoms.

Even the assumption that a conflict burns itself out (did not happen in Afghanistan and parts of Africa) does not hold. All parties involved will trade resources for ways to continue the conflict.

It could also get worse the faster technology progresses. But as the effect spirals at some point technology producing centers are caught up in the perma-war is the only thing preventing any side from escaping this wood chipper by leveling up.

So what creates this circumstances? Proxy wars- and a running out of resources to bribe the species, without a chance to find new easy reachable ones. Add to that the likelihood of any species, to adapt to a swinging habitat, early in its evolution and you are stuck for all eternity within a behavioral loop.

As this ending is not properly sugarcoated for futurists https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurism - here is an addendum.
In theory one could escape this by heavily modifying the species stuck- for example by introducing social networks, implants and other cybernetic crutches to the behaviour. What would walk away from that, capable to remain "social" even in dire times, able to peacefully give up on itself for a group or idea, capable to be morally stable even in abstract big groups, would be barely resembling a human.

Answer (score 0):

### The Gods Demand It

While some lesser religions use religion as a scapegoat for their petty wars, the eternal battle is demanded by our gods. All peoples, at least those who believe in our gods, send warriors every year to join the great eternal battle in the spaces between our homelands.

Though it costs us the lives of many of our great young people, it keeps us safe from the gods' wrath, and it's not so easy for mortal enemies to invade through an eternal war either; our holy warriors do not take kindly to heretics who think themselves brave enough to wield a weapon but too cowardly to fight for the gods.

---

What you basically have here is border regions between religously-claimed homelands which are constantly supplied with new warriors for religious reasons. The various "sides" reorganize weekly or monthly or yearly to mix things up, but it's more or less a massive training grounds.

I imagine the warriors of all sides would often congregate and have a few nights of good fun before setting back off to battle. Perhaps there are sacred common grounds where they all meet after battle to drink and discuss tactics, even with the "enemy".

Answer (score -2):

The standard human condition leads to a lot of fighting. People have multiple children who need feeding and there is always a limit to the resources available. Young men need to fight. Enough people have learned that it is easier to take resources from someone else than to do the hard work of growing or gathering food yourself. Population growth leads to fighting.

Thus, hunter-gatherer societies have had ritual warfare or regular raiding events. One anthropologist reported that the small group he was with (in the Amazon) was raided about once every 3 weeks.

The more organized the society, the larger the fighting and raiding.